Sequences of solutions of Poisson equation
this semester I'm taking my first course in Partial Differential Equations and I'm having a problem with the following exercise. It's from a guide of exercises that our teacher's assistant gave us.
Problem 11. Let for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ there is an $u_k \in C^{2}(\Omega)\cap C(\bar{\Omega})$ solution of the problem:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
-\Delta u_{k+1} &= f(u_k),\:\text{in $\Omega$}\\
u_{k+1} &= 0,\:\text{on $\partial\Omega$}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is bounded and regular. Also we'll assume $f$ is non-decreasing.
1)If $u_0$ satisfy
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
-\Delta u_{0} &= f(u_0),\:\text{in $\Omega$}\\
u_{0} &\geq 0,\:\text{on $\partial\Omega$}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Prove that $u_k$ is non-decreasing
2)If $u_{*}$ satisfy
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
-\Delta u_{*} &\leq f(u_k),\:\text{in $\Omega$}\\
u_{*} &\leq 0,\:\text{on $\partial\Omega$}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Prove that $u_k\geq u_*$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$
My question is. How do I start any of this two problems? I was thinking of using the Green's function but doesn't seem the correct way to do this excercise.
Any hint will be appreciated.

Meandering to start a problem, I might see what happens in part 1 when I set $k = 1$ and then $k = 2$.  Maybe I can see how to do an induction?  Then for part 2, see what happens for $k=0$ and then $k=1$?

I got that $u_1+C\leq u_0$ and something with the normal derivative for the $k,k+1$ case

I'll prove the inductive step in 1) and let you try the rest.
Suppose that $k\geq 1$ and $u_0,u_1,\dots,u_{k+1}\in C^2(\Omega) \cap C(\overline \Omega)$ satisfy the given PDEs and assume, for the sake of induction, that $u_k\geq u_{k-1}$ in $\overline\Omega$. Since $f$ is non-decreasing, it follows that \begin{align*}
-\Delta (u_{k+1}-u_k)&=f(u_k)-f(u_{k-1})\geq 0 .
\end{align*}  Hence, $$ -\Delta (u_{k+1}-u_k) \geq 0 \qquad\text{in } \Omega $$ and $u_{k+1}-u_k=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, so the maximum principle implies that $u_{k+1}\geq u_k$.
